# Program asks twice for number if wrong data is input first

Tags: python

I am very new to Python (started 2 days ago). I was trying to validate positive integers. The code does validate the numbers but it asks twice after a wrong input is entered. For example if I enter the word *Python*, it says: This is not an integer! like is supposed to but if I enter *20* afterwards, it also says it is not an integer and if I enter *20* again it reads it.

```
def is_positive_integer(input):
    #error: when a non-integer is input and then an integer is input it takes two tries to read the integer
    flag = 0
    while flag != 1:
        try:
            input = int(input)
            if input <= 0:
                print "This is not a positive integer!"
                input = raw_input("Enter the number again:")

        except ValueError:
            print "This is not an integer!" 
            input = raw_input("Enter the number again: ")             

        if isinstance(input, int):
            flag = 1
            return input

number = raw_input("Enter the number to be expanded: ")
is_positive_integer(number)
number = int(is_positive_integer(number))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main bug is that you call `is_positive_integer(number)` twice with the same input (the first thing you enter).

The first time you call `is_positive_integer(number)`, you throw away the return value. Only the second time do you assign the result to `number`.

You can "fix" your program by removing the line with just `is_positive_integer(number)` on its own.

However, your code is a little messy, and the name `is_positive_integer` does not describe what the function actually does.

I would refactor a little like this:

```
def input_positive_integer(prompt):
    input = raw_input(prompt)
    while True:
        try:
            input = int(input)
            if input <= 0:
                print "This is not a positive integer!"
            else:
                return input
        except ValueError:
            print "This is not an integer!"

        input = raw_input("Enter the number again: ")

number = input_positive_integer("Enter the number to be expanded: ")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I don't understand something of your code though. How does the while loop condition becomes false?

Comment: It never does, but the loop is exited with the `return input` line. A `return` statement automatically breaks out of loops inside the function it's returning from.

Comment: That's why your original code doesn't actually need the line `flag = 1`, since you `return` immediately after you do that.

Comment: I didn't know that, that's why I used a flag. It was the only thing that came to my mind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact that you're calling `is_positive_integer` *twice*. So, the first time it's called, you send it a string like `'hello'`, then it says it's not an integer and tells you to try again. Then you enter `'20'`, which parses fine, and it's returned.

But then you don't save a reference to that, so it goes nowhere.

Then you call the function again, this time saving a reference to it, and it first tries the original bad string, which was still there in `number`. Then it complains that it's a bad input, asks you for a new one, and you provide it, terminating the program.